# The derived category of $p$-complete abelian groups is comonadic over the derived category of $\mathbb F_p$-vector spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

$\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Let $p$ be a prime. The adjunction

$$\mathbb F_p \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (-) : \Mod(\mathbb Z) \rightleftarrows \Mod(\mathbb F_p) : U $$

descends (almost tautologically) to an adjunction on the Bousfield localization,

$$\mathbb F_p \otimes_\mathbb{Z} (-) : \Mod(\mathbb Z)^\wedge_p \rightleftarrows \Mod(\mathbb F_p) : U $$

I believe this adjunction is comonadic, and I believe this is well-known.

**Question 1:** What is a reference for the comonadicity of the above adjunction?

**Question 2:** Are there any examples of folks applying this comonadicity to the study of infinite $p$-complete abelian groups (or — almost equivalently — to infinite abelian $p$-groups)?

**Notes:**

- In Bousfield's language, the statement is that the $\mathbb F_p$-nilpotent completion of a $\mathbb Z$-module always coincides with its $\mathbb F_p$-localization. This is related to saying something about the associated Adams spectral sequence, although I think for general objects of $\Mod(\mathbb Z)^\wedge_p$ there will still be $\varprojlim^1$ issues with the spectral sequence.
- It follows, for example, from the main result of [Baker–Lazarev](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105079) that the above adjunction is comonadic at the unit $\mathbb Z_p$ (and hence at any compact object), but I'm not sure about general objects. Also I think the above result should be older.
- This doesn't seem to follow from [Mathew's theory of descendable adjunctions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2156) — $\mathbb Z_p$ is not in the thick subcategory generated by $\mathbb F_p$.
- In case it's not obvious: in the above, I take an [implicit $\infty$-convention](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/implicit+infinity-category+theory+convention) and write $A = HA$ everywhere. $\Mod(R)$ is the stable $\infty$-category / dg-category of chain complexes of $R$-modules localized at quasi-isomorphism. $\Mod(\mathbb Z)^\wedge_p$ is the Bousfield localization of $\Mod(\mathbb Z)$ at $\mathbb F_p$. Alternatively, it is the stable $\infty$-category / dg-category of chain complexes of $p$-complete abelian groups localized at quasi-isomorphism. An abelian group $A$ is $p$-complete if it is a $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$-module and $\Ext^\ast(\mathbb Q, A) = 0$. For the comonadicity statement here, it's important to work with more than just the homotopy categories or just the hearts of these categories.

Comment: I think that this is a direct consequence of Beck's monadicity theorem (or more precisely, Lurie's generalization): the mod p functor is a left adjoint, conservative, and preserves totalizations of cosimplicial objects.

Comment: I agree with Z. M. Moreover, the mod $p$ functor preserves both limits and colimits, so it is both monadic and comonadic.

Comment: Why does the mod p functor preserve limits? What is its left adjoint?

Comment: TeX note: ${}^\to_\leftarrow$ `{}^\to_\leftarrow` is available without any need for tricky constructs as $\rightleftarrows$ `\rightleftarrows`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: The mod p functor is a finite colimit (the cofiber of multiplication by p), thus preserves (co)limits.

Comment: Theorem 2.30 (and its proof) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06869.pdf are relevant

Comment: @TimCampion The mod-$p$ functor is given by tensoring with $\Bbb F_p$, equivalent to the perfect complex $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ in degrees 0 and 1. This complex is dualizable with dual $\Bbb F_p[-1]$, and so $\Bbb F_p \otimes M \simeq map(\Bbb F_p[-1], M)$. This makes the left adjoint tensoring with $\Bbb F_p[-1] = map(\Bbb F_p, \Bbb Z)$.